# Couchbase GetView .NET - Query Failed

Tags: .net, mapreduce, nosql, view, couchbase

I was successful in storing my complex C# object (class with some properties) in to the Couchbase using the .NET Sdk. I also created a View and now im trying to get the data (collection of records) from the view. But when I use the GetView method, I always get the error "Query failed for view by_reviewerID in design document _design/Test"

```
var result = = CouchManager.Instance.GetView("_design/dev_Test", "by_reviewerID");
```

I have the view both in the Design and the Production. Above is for Design view.
When I go to the Couchbase server and use the http link to see the view result, I'm able to get the data as JSON. But when i do it through the code, I always get the above exception. Below is the part of the stack trace.

> Couchbase.d__0`1.MoveNext() +1687
>
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.Count(IEnumerable`1 source)

My Map function for the view is

```
function (doc,meta) {
  emit(doc, null);
}
```

Could you please kindly help me as i'm struck up in this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Found out the actual issue. The issue was in passing the right parameters for the GetView method.

```
var result = = CouchManager.Instance.GetView("dev_Test", "by_reviewerID");
```

Above is the correct code which works. The issue is that the design document name need not be prefixed with '**_design/**' . Sharing the code as it might help someone who is facing the same issue.

**Note:** the prefix '**dev_**' is for the Design View. For the Production View, this prefix must be removed.